# C How to Pass an Array of Arrays of Structs to a function?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Person {
    char name[100];
    int age;
    char secondName[100];
} Person;

int printA(Person **arrayA) {
    printf("here\n\n");
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++) {
            printf("%s\n", (*((arrayA+j) + i))->name);
        }
        printf("DONE Array\n\n");
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    Person person1;
    Person person2;
    Person person3;
    Person person4;
    Person person5;
    Person person6;
    
    strcpy(person1.name, "John");
    strcpy(person2.name, "Will");
    strcpy(person3.name, "Bill");
    strcpy(person4.name, "Tim");
    strcpy(person5.name, "Andrew");
    strcpy(person6.name, "Sarah");
    
    strcpy(person1.secondName, "Smith");
    strcpy(person2.secondName, "Johnson");
    strcpy(person3.secondName, "Brown");
    strcpy(person4.secondName, "Williams");
    strcpy(person5.secondName, "Jones");
    strcpy(person6.secondName, "Garcia");
    
    person1.age = 20;
    person2.age = 25;
    person3.age = 30;
    person4.age = 35;
    person5.age = 40;
    person6.age = 45;
    
    Person array1[3];
    Person array2[3];
    
    array1[0] = person1;
    array1[1] = person2;
    array1[2] = person3;
    
    array2[0] = person4;
    array2[1] = person5;
    array2[2] = person6;
    
    Person *arrayMain[2];
    
    arrayMain[0] = array1;
    arrayMain[1] = array2;
    
    printA(arrayMain);
}
```

Above is the best I have managed to make, but I can't get it to work properly. What I am trying to achieve is passing an array of arrays of structs to a function and allowing the function to view the struct values.

This outputs a few values although in the wrong order ("John", then "Tim") and then seg-faults.

Comment: Whenever I see "parallel" definitions (e.g. `Person p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6;`), I want to convert those to an _array_ (e.g. `Person persons[6];`). Because of this, you need an extra/indirect pointer array (`arrayMain`). But, if this is cleaned up, we don't need to pass an _indirect_ pointer array to `printA`. (i.e.) We can eliminate `arrayMain` and, in `main`, we can just do: `printA(persons);` and change to: `int printA(Person *arrayA)`

Comment: Usually it is more scalable to have a [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) of people. `struct person_array { size_t size, capacity; struct Person *data; }` then `void printA(struct person_array *)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems, both of which are here:

```
printf("%s\n", (*((arrayA+j) + i))->name);
```

First, you've got your array indices mixed up.  Second, you've got the dereference in the wrong place.  The above is the same as:

```
printf("%s\n", (*(arrayA + j + i))->name);
```

Which doesn't make sense.  You need to move the dereference operator inside one set of parenthesis and swap the indices:

```
printf("%s\n", ((*(arrayA+i) + j))->name);
```

Or better yet, use array index notation:

```
printf("%s\n", arrayA[i][j].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here we have a few mistakes.

The one is that you are trying to get the `name` value from the variable declared as a stack, not a heap. When a variable is declared as a stack (with `[n]`), we use simple `.` to get access to its value. When a variable is declared as a heap (with `*`) and is known as a pointer, we use `*` and `->` (if a variable in a struct) to get access to its value.

The other is that you messed up with iterators. You have to look at the array in reverse order of the declaration, as you declared `arrayMain` with `[2]` items that had been declared with `[3]` each previously. So, here is how `arrayMain` looks:

```
arrayMain => [array1[3], array2[3]];
arrayMain[0] => [person1, person2, person3];
arrayMain[0][0] => parson1;
```

Therefore, the right way to get access to `name` from stack arrays would be:

```
arrayA[i][j].name
```